# Disable / enable amfid on per-application basis

Tags: macos, security, monterey, code-signing

I want to create and manage snapshots on my `Data` partition, but because I don't have a developer certificate and apple-granted entitlements (like `com.apple.developer.vfs.snapshot`), I have to either disable amfid entirely (nvram boot-args="amfi_get_out_of_my_way=0x1") which would allow me to run the ad-hoc signed binary or give up using the tool, both of which I would rather prefer to avoid. I've heard the `amfi` is an important security feature?

Is there a way to disable `amfi` on a per-app basis, i.e. configure it to skip checking certain application's signature and run it directly?

The program I'm trying to use is https://github.com/ahl/apfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately the macOS kernel does not include functionality that would allow you to excempt specific programs from AMFI checks.

A third party solution has been made here:

https://github.com/osy/AMFIExemption

Basically this works by adding a third-party kernel extension to the system that lets you setup a whitelist of entitlements that are left unchecked. I.e. you can specify that programs can have the `com.apple.developer.vfs.snapshot` snapshot without a valid signature from Apple.

Note that this means that other programs than your own are also exempt from checking this particular entitlement.

A compatibility note: You write that this needs to work on macOS Monterey. I haven't tested the kernel extension on Monterey, so it might not be updated for that. It has been tested to work on Big Sur (the version before Monterey).

Another possibility that works without a kernel extension is to manually patch the running `amfid` program (that actually performs the entitlement checks) in memory to allow any entitlement in binaries signed by your Developer ID key instead of only allowing Apple's.

A script to do just that on Sierra has been posted here:

https://gist.github.com/pvieito/c0c9b8fd73255b57927b273d329c5800

Note that you need to have SIP disabled before you can do this, as otherwise you cannot change the contents of memory owned by the `amfid` process.

Note that the script only works on Sierra. The author has published a [blog post](https://pvieito.com/2016/12/amfid-patching) on how the script works. To update the script for Monterey, you would need to follow the same steps to locate the correct location of the instruction inside `amfid` to modify.

Comment: I'm using Apple Silicon and it appears that the extension you linked to is x86 only.

Comment: Ah, your question did not state that you were on Apple Silicon - as you specifically wrote Monterey, it sounded logical that you were on older hardware given that you're running an older operating system. But yes, right now, the AMFIExemption extension does not work on Apple Silicon Macs.